# git meaning of pound sign # before and after filename?

Tags: git

I've googled this all over the place and can't find any explanation.

I run git status and in amongst the list of modified files/folders that that command outputs is this:

```
folder/subfolder/text.txt
```

... and in the list of untracked files is this:

```
folder/subfolder/#text.txt#
```

What does the latter mean?
Why is that file in untracked files, and what do the pound signs mean?

I've done work on that file, so I know it's telling me something about it. But what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the "autosave". It is the copy version of the file that the editor creates. You have to explicitly tell git to ignore these files in gitignore file.

Comment: out of curiosity, which editors use this pattern for their auto-saved backups?

Comment: ahh... okay that explains it. I had copied/pasted file contents from bluefish to emacs but could swear I had not saved the emacs file... guess I had saved it after all. Thanks, that had me pretty confused

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with git.

It a file which is being created by some external program like editor, IDE etc.
You can add this pattern to be ignored in your `.gitignore` file so it will not be tracked

```
// .gitignore
#*
```